# Как обработать postgres таблицу в Golang

Tags: postgresql, golang

Работаю с postgres в golang, в базе есть функция, которая возвращает table с набором полей.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как распарсить результат с таким типом в golang?

```
var D []*domain.Tariff
rows, err := p.ConnPool.Query(ctx, "/*no load balance*/SELECT billing.lists.tariffs()")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        tDomain := domain.Tariff{}
        err := rows.Scan(&tDomain)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        D = append(D, &tDomain)
    }

type Tariff struct {
    TariffID           TariffID   `db:"tariff_id"`
    TariffName         string     `db:"tariff_name"`
    FreeWorkplace      int64      `db:"free_workplace"`
    DiskSpaceQuota     float64    `db:"disk_space_quota"`
    BillingFree        bool       `db:"billing_free"`
    BillingFullTime    bool       `db:"billing_full_time"`
    PeriodDays         int64      `db:"period_days"`
    CostWorkplace      float64    `db:"cost_workplace"`
    Currency           string     `db:"currency"`
    RecalcChangeTariff bool       `db:"recalc_change_tariff"`
    MaxVoiceUser       int64      `db:"max_voice_user"`
    MaxVideoUser       int64      `db:"max_video_user"`
    DefaultTariff      bool       `db:"default_tariff"`
    OpenDate           time.Time  `db:"open_date"`
    CloseDate          *time.Time `db:"close_date"`
    Status             string     `db:"status"`
}
```

вот список полей, который возвращает функция

```
create function tariffs()
    returns TABLE(tariff_id bigint, tariff_name character varying, status character varying, open_date timestamp without time zone, close_date timestamp without time zone, free_workplace integer, disk_space_quota numeric, billing_free boolean, billing_full_time boolean, cost_workplace numeric, currency character varying, period_days integer, default_tariff boolean, recalc_change_tariff boolean, max_voice_user integer, max_video_user integer)
    language plpgsql
```

пыталась и в строку, и сразу в слайс структур, не получается.

Comment: а что конкретно не получается? ошибки какие?

Comment: а тип `TariffID` - это int64 ?

Comment: Сделайте `select * from billing.lists.tariffs()` и получите результат как будто просто читаете из таблицы, а не одно поле табличного типа